# Using Computer Modern \int symbol, with txfonts math font

Tags: fonts, symbols, txfonts

I would like to use the standard `\int` and the `\gammaup` from the `txfonts` package. How can I mix these symbols?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
    Not the int I like, but the gammaup I do like:
    \[\int \gammaup\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that the `txfonts` package is deprecated. You should use `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` instead.

Comment: Thank you @PhelypeOleinik, I did not know that! Upon exchanging `txfonts` with `newtxmath` it doesn't change the `\int` symbol, just as i wanted. That solves my question.

Comment: Hm... Actually the symbol _does_ change, but the integral symbol is similar (but not identical) to Computer Modern's...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accidental answer :-)

The `txfonts` package is obsolete, and you usually can replace it by `newtxtext` (for the text fonts) and `newtxmath` (for, you guessed, the math fonts). However the `\int` symbol for `newtxmath` is rather similar to Computer Modern's, so it might work for you. Here's a comparison between them (left to right: `txfonts`, Computer Modern, and `newtxmath`):

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}% For text font
\usepackage{newtxmath}
% From txfonts
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolstx}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\txintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolstx}{"52}
\DeclareRobustCommand\txint{\txintop\nolimits}
% From Computer Modern
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolscmr}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmrintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolscmr}{"52}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cmrint{\cmrintop\nolimits}
\begin{document}
  \[\txint \cmrint \int \gammaup\]
\end{document}
```

---

To find the symbols it takes a bit of digging through the sources (that's how I did it, at least; there might be a better way).

#### `\cmrint`

The Computer Modern definition of the symbols can be found in `fontmath.ltx` (that's where LaTeX math fonts are initialised. You can find that file by running `kpsewhich fontmath.ltx` in a terminal).  Searching for `\int` in the code you'll see that it's defined as:

```latex
    \DeclareRobustCommand\int{\intop\nolimits}
```

which means that `\int` is just `\intop\nolimits` (`\nolimits` is a TeX primitive), and `\intop` is defined just above with:

```latex
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"52}
```

which means that it is a `\mathop` (operator) taken from slot number `"52` (that's hexadecimal 0x52) from the `largesymbols` font.  Finally, the `largesymbols` font is declared at the beginning of `fontmath.ltx` with:

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
```

which means encoding `OMX`, family `cmex`, series `m`(edium), shape `n`(ormal).

To make the example above I just renamed `largesymbols` to `largesymbolscmr` and `\int(op)` to `\cmrint(op)` to avoid conflicts.

#### `\txint`

The process is similar, except that instead of looking into `fontmath.ltx` we'll look at `txfonts.sty` (use `kpsewhich txfonts.sty` to find the file).  Though `txfonts.sty` doesn't redefine `\int`, so the definition of the *command* is the same as LaTeX's original.  What `txfonts` does redefine is the `largesymbols` math font:

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
```

so to take the `txfonts` version of `\int` we need to declare that font and make a separate copy that uses `txex` rather than `cmex`:

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolstx}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n} % declare a TX copy of largesymbols
\DeclareMathSymbol{\txintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolstx}{"52} % declare a TX copy of \intop that uses the above
\DeclareRobustCommand\txint{\txintop\nolimits}
```

#### `\txiint`

This one is similar to the above.  In `txfonts.sty` you'll find that `\iint` is defined with:

```latex
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{33}
   \def\iint{\iintop\nolimits}
```

which uses `largesymbolsA`, defined previously with:

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{U}{txexa}{m}{n}
```

so you can adapt (to avoid the `\re@Declare...` command defined in that package):

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolstxA}{U}{txexa}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\txiintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolstxA}{"21} % 33 (decimal) = "21 (hexadecimal)
\DeclareRobustCommand\txiint{\txiintop\nolimits}
```

Another way you could find a glyph in a font is by using the `fonttable` package, for example with `{U}{txexa}{m}{n}`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\xfonttable{U}{txexa}{m}{n}
\end{document}
```

which outputs:

> [image]

that shows the double integral glyph in slot 33 of that font.

#### `\cmriint`

The Computer Modern font doesn't have a double integral glyph, so the approach above won't work. But there are other options:

**`amsmath`** emulates (up to) 4 integral signs with `\MultiIntegral`, which is defined:

```latex
\newcommand{\MultiIntegral}[1]{%
  \edef\ints@c{\noexpand\intop
    \ifnum#1=\z@\noexpand\intdots@\else\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\tw@\noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \ifnum#1>\thr@@\noexpand\intop\noexpand\intkern@\fi
    \noexpand\intop
    \noexpand\ilimits@
  }%
  \futurelet\@let@token\ints@a
}
```

and then `\iint` is defined as:

```latex
\ams@newcommand{\iint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{2}}
```

However this will use the default `\intop` glyph.  To change the font you can create a copy of (or even redefine) `\MultiIntegral` which uses (say) the `\cmrintop` defined above.

You can also use the **`esint`** package, which defines several types of integral signs using (a clone of) the Computer Modern glyph. To use the Computer Modern integral sign with other font packages you just have to make sure you load `esint` after all font packages (and after `amsmath`).

Comment: You should load `newtxtext` first and `newtxmath` second. Try to type a formula containing numbers with your present setup and you'll see why `:-)`

Comment: @campa Thanks! I didn't knew about this explicit order (though in my head was `newtxtext` always first, so I've never seen the problem before; not sure why I changed this time :-).

Comment: alright, so now i wanted to use `\iint`, but i don't understand what you did with the Declare* lines, where can i look up the "number" of the `\iint`?

Comment: @josh I added an explanation how I found the glyphs in the fonts and added the declaration of `\iint` in `txfonts`, plus some tips for looking up glyphs in fonts. I hope it's understandable.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes, thank you very much, this shows what little i actually know of what latex does to work in the background

Comment: well, i tried this, and it seems \iint is declared in amsmath, such that i dont have a symbol to override, i have to create my own \iint.

Comment: @josh Sorry, I messed up: I forgot you wanted the CMR integral, not the TX one. Indeed, it seems Computer Modern doesn't have an `\iint` glyph, that's why `amsmath` emulates that. Try with `esint`: you just need to load `\usepackage{esint}` after loading font packages, or do: `\DeclareSymbolFont{largeesint}{U}{esint}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmriintop}{\mathop}{largeesint}{"03}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cmriint{\cmriintop\nolimits}` if you want `\iint` only. Let me know if it solves your problem :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik indeed it has, 
I think i generally lack the understanding of how fonts and packages work in latex, i'm just stumbling my way through this somehow

Comment: @josh Don't worry, in some sense we all are ;-) I just found out about `esint`, which is much easier than declaring fonts manually. Indeed, the font declaration interface is not really supposed to be used by document authors, rather by font package authors, that's why it's somewhat complicated... I'll add `esint` to my answer above

Comment: including package `esint` _after_ `newtxmath` replaces all integral symbols with (I think) the computer modern variants.

Comment: Fira Math is missing \bigcap at the time of this comment. Your answer helped me arrive at: `\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolscmr}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}`
`\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmrbigcap}{\mathop}{largesymbolscmr}{"54}`