# İntegral symbol style

Tags: amsmath

How can I make the integral symbol as without removing the `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`?

I want this but I don't want to remove the `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
\[ \int 3\,dx\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want `MnSymbol`?  Is some other package interfering?  Do you not have `MnSymbol` installed on some other machine?  Does `MnSymbol` change some other symbol in ways you don't want?

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolscmr}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cmrintop}{\mathop}{largesymbolscmr}{"52}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cmrint{\cmrintop\nolimits}

\begin{document}
\[ \cmrint 3\,dx\]

\end{document}`...perhaps a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518936/using-computer-modern-int-symbol-with-txfonts-math-font

Comment: @Teepeemm The only problem now is the integral symbol. I want to make this symbol the same as before with this package installed. This shape is so bad.

Comment: I think it will work for me thank you :) @Steven B. Segletes

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Is it possible to a little more enlarge this symbol ?

Comment: If you load `MnSymbol` for its special symbols, don't. Their shapes are for usage with Minion and don't really blend with other fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be try this package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{esint} % various fancy integral symbols
\begin{document}
\[\int \iint \oint \oiint \varoiint \]
\[ \int 3\,dx\]
\end{document}
```